# Declaring Function type with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know I have asked this before, and I cannot find the question nor remember the answer.

I have an object with several methods with the same signature:

```
{

  foo: function(){
    return [];   // (return Array<T>)
  },

  bar: function(){
    return [];   // (return Array<T>)
  },

  baz: function(){
    return [];   // (return Array<T>)
  }

}
```

When I declare the interface for this object:

```
interface SomeObj {

   foo: Function,
   bar: Function,
   baz: Function

}
```

but I want to declare a type for these functions, something like this:

```
  type TestSuiteGetterFn <T>() => Array<T>;

  interface SomeObj {

       foo: TestSuiteGetterFn,
       bar: TestSuiteGetterFn,
       baz: TestSuiteGetterFn

    }
```

but this does not compile.

I have rarely found something so difficult to Google as this one.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20UpdateFn%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(name%3A%20string)%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Message%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20updateFn%3A%20UpdateFn%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20message%3A%20Message%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20updateFn(name%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%60updated%3A%20%24%7Bname%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D

Comment: @peeskillet thanks, maybe that works, but I think gyre's answer is more ideal?

Comment: @Chris I got a red squiggly in my IDE (Webstorm), I didn't need to transpile to know there would be an error, but doubt it would be a meaningful error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply forgot the equals sign when declaring your function type.

[TypeScript Playground Permalink](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20%20%20type%20TestSuiteGetterFn%3CT%3E%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20Array%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20SomeObj%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20TestSuiteGetterFn%3Cstring%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20TestSuiteGetterFn%3Cnumber%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20baz%3A%20TestSuiteGetterFn%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

```
type TestSuiteGetterFn<T> = () => Array<T>;

interface SomeObj {
     foo: TestSuiteGetterFn<string>,
     bar: TestSuiteGetterFn<number>,
     baz: TestSuiteGetterFn<string>
}
```

Comment: Glad to help! Learned something new about TypeScript myself, too.

Comment: ditto if you think it's a well framed question

Comment: Guys what is that `<T>` ?

Comment: <T> is the generic type, it must be passed in, see the 3 times it is passed